# How can I update Ease of Access settings from a script in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, control-panel

In Windows 10, in **Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the computer easier to see**, there is a checkbox named "Remove background images (where available)".

[image: Remove background images]

I would like to set and unset this checkbox from a batch script or a PowerShell script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This stackoverflow article might get you started in the right direction [Automate Windows 7 Ease of Access Setting “Turn off unnecessary animations”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817160/automate-windows-7-ease-of-access-setting-turn-off-unnecessary-animations)

Comment: @thomschumacher it doesn't help me. I still don't know which registry key/value I need to use